# Create complicated text formulas in graphics

Tags: graphics

I want to put somewhat complicated, or at least non-standardly formatted, text on some of my graphics. For example, I'd like to be able to use `f^[4](x)` (where the `^[4]` should obviously be a superscript rather than `f^(4)[x]` for the fourth derivative as a plot label. I'd like to control the formatting of various mathematical objects (for example, I'd like `x^2+x+1` to be written that way rather than as `1+x+x^2`), and the like.

The only way I've found for doing this is actually building up the string using StyleBox'es, which is both time-consuming and ugly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you looked into TraditionalForm?

Comment: You may use `Row`and typeset "offending" parts as strings.

Comment: Please include a sample of the StyleBox code you are using that produces the output you desire.

Comment: Here are two previous answers that address these issues: [Formula Formatting is Small and Chunky?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6165/245) and [Using a function name instead of its definition in AxesLabel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3296/245)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general answer for what you appear to be doing is to wrap your expressions in `HoldForm`. However, it depends on how you include the expression. For example, here I'm using `PlotLabel` and have no problem:

```
Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> x^2 + x + 1]
```

[image: plotlabel]

However, what if I want to permute the order of the terms to `x + 1 + x^2`? Then `HoldForm` does the job:

```
Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[x + 1 + x^2]]
```

[image: plotlabel 2]

**Edit**

I just noticed the second part of your question about the derivative format. The documentation on formatting is indeed somewhat confusing because it's spread through different pages. Maybe that has to do with the fact that there are so many different methods that it's hard to identify the "officially preferred" approach. I'm thinking, for example, of the `Notation` package which seems like it's supposed to make custom notation easier but which is actually a bit clumsy to use.

The default style for labels in plots is `TraditionalForm`, so I'll restrict the style modifications to that particular output form. Here is *one* way that you could make plot labels appear with the formatting for derivatives that you describe in the question:

```
Derivative /: 
 MakeBoxes[Derivative[\[Alpha]__][f1_][vars__Symbol], 
  TraditionalForm] := RowBox[
  Flatten@{SuperscriptBox[ToBoxes[f1], 
     RowBox[Flatten@{"[", Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {\[Alpha]}], ","], 
        "]"}]], "(", Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {vars}], ","], ")"}]
```

Now you should be able to do the following:

```
Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[f'[x]]]
```

and the plot label will look like this:

> $f^{[1]}(x)$

I added some extra logic to the style definition to make it work with higher-order derivatives and many variables, too.

As another example, you would input a mixed higher-order derivative like `HoldForm[Derivative[1, 2][f][x, y]]` and the display would be

> $f^{[1,2]}(x,y)$

This modification will affect the display of all derivatives that were entered using the `Derivative` keyword when the output format is `TraditionalForm`. So if you want it to appear that way when `TraditionalForm` *isn't* the default, you'll have to wrap the expression in `TraditionalForm` explicitly. Also note that the `TraditionalForm` display of the alternative derivative `D[f[x],x]` is *not* affected by the new format, whereas `f'[x]` is. So you can still choose between two different `TraditionalForm` appearances for derivatives - a nontraditional and a traditional one...

**Edit 2**

Some additional links:

- [Notation of partial derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3791/245)
- [How to make Jacobian automatically in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5790/245)
- [Formula Formatting is Small and Chunky?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6164/245)
- [Using a function name instead of its definition in AxesLabel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3290/245)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find this in the docs, somehow. That should solve many problems -- but how about formatting higher derivatives using [n] rather than (n)? Must that   be hand-coded, or is there some other way?

Comment: I've added an answer to the second part of your question. You have to hand-code the formatting _once_, of course; but then it will be automatic whenever you display `Derivative`s in `TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you want to have it somewhere inside the image, rather than as a label, you may use Epilog like this:

```
 Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> 
   Inset[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)+x+1", 16, Red, 
   Italic], Scaled[{0.6, 0.2}]], ImageSize -> 200]
```

giving you this

[image: Example image 1]

Otherwise you may use Show[ ] to combine your graphic with any text (that should be first transformed into a graphic object):

```
 Show[{Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200],
   Graphics[
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)+x+1", 16, 
   RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0], Italic], Scaled[{0.4, 0.6}]]]
 }]
```

[image: Example image 2]

Comment: Where is the documentation on the syntax "!(*SuperscriptBox[(x), (2)])+x+1"?

Comment: Oh, I just typed the formula between the quotes in the Style operator; plain in my notebook as to get it in the form it is presented on the graph. It may be done, say, using the Basic Math Input palette. But when copy-pasting it here all these strange things (like \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)) appeared. Excuse me for have not noticed them. One may use the following: Graphics[Text[
  Style[TraditionalForm[x^4 + x + 1], 16, RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0], 
   Italic], Scaled[{0.4, 0.6}]]] instead.