# Running external pdflatex command and importing the generated PDF document

Tags: import, latex, pdf-format

There have been a couple of questions about incorporating labels and equations that were typeset in $\LaTeX$ into a *Mathematica* notebook. Ideally, this requires running `pdflatex` (or `latex`) from within *Mathematica* and then importing the generated `PDF` document.

Unfortunately, importing of `PDF` is known to be buggy, as discussed in these questions (among others, probably):

- [Mathematica PDF import and fonts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9030/245)
- [Difficulties with Importing PDFs in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2781/245)
- [Combine multiple PDF files into one document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13251/245)
- [What kind of PDF files that MMA does not read (import)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69853/what-kind-of-pdf-files-that-mma-does-not-read-import)

The last two also mention `ghostscript` as the way to solve some of the issues, in particular using the `pdfwrite` device to re-generate a new `PDF` from existing ones.

This could be used in a $\LaTeX$ workflow like this (I am assuming **Mac OS X** here):

```
Export["words.tex", "\n\\nonstopmode
  \\documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \\begin{document}\n
  here\\qquad we\\qquad go
  \\end{document}\n
  ", "Text"];

Run["pdflatex words"]

(* ==> 0 *)

Import["words.pdf"]
```

> `Import::general: Expected cross reference table >>`
>
> `Import::general: Expected cross reference table >>`
>
> `Import::general: Could not find document trailer >>`
>
> `General::stop:`

As was to be expected, here we get error messages similar to what the second question referenced above saw. So now try the `ghostscript` workaround. Since this question aims at using $\LaTeX$, by assumption we have a working $\TeX$ installation which nowadays includes `ghostscript`, so the following will be able to execute:

```
Run["gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOCACHE \
-sOutputFile=words-nofont.pdf -q -dBatch -dNOPAUSE words.pdf -c quit"]

(* ==> 0 *)

Import["words-nofont.pdf"]
```

[image: wrong spacing]

But the imported `PDF` has incorrect spacings between the words. It should (as you can tell from the `\\qquad` in the source) look more like

> $\text{Here}\qquad \text{we}\qquad \text{go}$

This is just a somewhat artificial example illustrating the general problem of incorrect lengths and fonts upon import of a `PDF`.

So the question is, how can one fix this, either by using $\TeX$ and its companion utilities differently, or by relying only on *Mathematica*'s capabilities? If this can be done, then it will be possible to automate the generation of $\LaTeX$ labels etc. from within *Mathematica*.

I'll post my answer based on `ghostscript` below, hoping that eventually someone will come up with a fix for `PDF` import that doesn't require external software.

Comment: I can't believe that even after writing MaTeX, I never noticed this thread before!

Answer (score 6):

**Only expected to work for Mac OS X and linux (Windows has ghostscript, but calls have different syntax):**

The reason why the errors happen in the first place is that `pdflatex` generates one of the more recent versions of the `PDF` specification (1.5), whereas *Mathematica* expects an older version upon import (probably 1.3). Specifying the lower version by adding `\pdfminorversion=3` as the first line of the source gets rid of the error messages but doesn't fix the spacings.

A possible work-around is to replace the `ghostscript` call in the question by a two-step process that first converts the $\LaTeX$ generated to `Postscript` and then passes it to the `ps2pdf` command which also comes with the $\TeX$ distribution. This seems to remove the features of the modern `PDF` that trip up *Mathematica*'s import handling:

```
Run["gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q \
-dbatch -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET words.pdf -c quit | ps2pdf - wordNew.pdf"]

(* ==> 0 *)

Import["wordNew.pdf"]
```

[image: Correct spacing]

To tie this together into a *Mathematica* function that typesets a given source string, I'll change the standard preamble of the test file above into something nicer:

```
latex[str_] := Module[
  {p,
   TeXsource = "\n\\nonstopmode
    \\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
    \\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
    \\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
    \\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
    \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic \
characters\n
    \\begin{document}\n
    ***BODY***
    \\end{document}\n
    ",
   sourceFile = 
    FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, 
      "MathematicaOutput" <> 
       StringJoin[Map[ToString, DateList[]]]}]},
  Export[sourceFile <> ".tex", 
   StringReplace[TeXsource, "***BODY***" -> str], "Text"];
  SetDirectory["/tmp"];
  Run["pdflatex " <> sourceFile];
  Run["gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dbatch \
-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET " <> sourceFile <> ".pdf -c quit | ps2pdf - " <> 
    sourceFile <> "-nofont.pdf"];
  p = First@Import[sourceFile <> "-nofont.pdf"];
  DeleteFile[FileNames[sourceFile <> "*.*"]];
  ResetDirectory[];
  p
  ]
```

Now you can use this function as follows:

```
latex[
 "The answer is\\quad 
   $\\displaystyle\\frac{\\alpha}{2}\\int_0^\\infty f(x)\\,dx$"
]
```

[image: example PDF]

This allows transparent $\LaTeX$ typesetting from within *Mathematica*, and the `standalone` class makes sure that the output `PDF` is nicely cropped.

As I said, this is a workaround that will become unnecessary as soon as someone finds a *Mathematica*-only route to import `PDF` properly.

Comment: If you only want PostScript, not PDF, you could also call `latex` and then `dvips`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But then to import it, I'd still need to convert to `PDF` again (using `ps2dpf` which I use above as well), so the total number of steps seems to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if Mathematica could at least say that the error lies in the pdf version mismatch. Thanks @Jens.

Here is another way to fix a pdf generated from pdflatex to be `Import`able in Mathematica, using Ghostscript (here on windows, but parameters should be similar on other operating systems):

This just converts the pdf to PDF v1.3.

```
gswin64c.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNoOutputFonts -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -o output.pdf input.pdf
```

---

Full example ("true `TeXForm`", assuming the programs are in your `PATH`):

```
$s = StringTemplate["\\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
    \\usepackage{amsmath}
    \\usepackage{amssymb}

    \\begin{document}
    $\\displaystyle ``$
    \\end{document}
    "][
   (
      a x^2 + b x + c == 0
      ) // TeXForm // ToString
   ];
Export["temp.tex", $s, "String"];
RunProcess@{"pdflatex.exe", "temp.tex"};
RunProcess@{"gswin64c.exe", "-q", 
   "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite", "-dNoOutputFonts", "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3", "-o", 
   "output.pdf", "temp.pdf"};
Import@"output.pdf"//First
```

Output:
$$a x^2+b x+c=0$$

Comment: You need to use the `-dNoOutputFonts` option, available in Ghostscript 9.15 or later, otherwise Mathematica will mess up many glyphs. This shouldn't be a disadvantage because Mathematica does outline the fonts on import anyway. This is what I use in [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).  BTW I've never seen this thread before.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, thanks for that. I was already beginning to wonder how I could fix `Import::general: Unimplemented operator ' encountered` which I got for running it on `IdentityMatrix@3`. I need to check out MaTeX.

Comment: MaTeX does basically the same thing that you are showing here.  Except it has all (well, most of ...) the issues ironed out.  There's an incredible amount of stuff that can go wrong unexpectedly. E.g. did you know that if you just switch out that StringTemplate to FileTemplate then things will blow up on Windows?  Who would think of that?  (FileTemplate has bad CR/LF handling)

Comment: Thanks for making it simpler, and also covering the Windows side which I had no way of testing (+1). @Szabolcs Great work on MaTeX - especially since there's so much insidious stuff going wrong with PDF.