# Rendering percent symbol in the correct typeface

Tags: formatting, fonts

When I do

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 Epilog -> 
  Style[Text["b: 5%", Scaled[{0.05, 0.05}], {-1, -1}], 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]
```

[image]

the percent symbol is shown in the wrong typeface, possibly Times. How can I make it display in the correct face?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way in which I've ever been able to achieve fully consistent typesetting in *Mathematica* is to use Times font for everything, or to use external [$\LaTeX$ processing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16955/245). Since the default notebook style has changed to Arial in version 9, many inconsistencies like the one you observe are revealed, and I haven't found a good answer how to fix that while using sans serif fonts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematica automatically replaces many operators found in normal text fonts with operators in a Mathematica font. You can change that behavior as follows:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```

Test:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
   Epilog -> Style[Text["b: 5%", Scaled[{0.05, 0.05}], {-1, -1}], 
                    FontFamily -> "GiddyupStd", 20]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In the notebook, this works indeed (+1), but when you export it to `PDF` the problem **re-appears**. Also, it re-appears of course when you copy the graphic to another notebook.  So the substitution doesn't appear to get turned off for good, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jens The OP says nothing about EPS. The question is: "How can I make it **display** in the correct face?". Other Notebooks can be served by replacing `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd`.

Comment: @Jens, you can set this globally using `SetOptions[Graphics,BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}} ]` or `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]`

Comment: @verbeia Uhm... The latter part is already in my previous comment

Comment: @Verbeia Using `$FrontEnd` as @Sjoerd said seems to fix the problem with `Export` too. It works for percent and a few other special cases, but **not in general**. For example, take the character `\[HBar]`.

Comment: @jens I guess the problem with `\[HBar]` is that it isn't part of most font sets and that a Mathematica font version needs to be used anyway. This, then, may not be aesthetically matched with the text font you use.

Comment: Yes, that's true - your answer solves the problem as specified in the question, my last remark was more motivated by the general problem I had pointed out [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16154/245).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries whoops, sorry, need more coffee!

Comment: It seems this not work in the version of 13.3.1.

Answer (score 7):

An addition to Sjoerd's answer.

`Style` can be used for setting global FrontEnd or Notebook preferences locally. So it is better to move the `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}` option directly in the `Style` expression rather than changing global preferences. It also solves the problems with `Export` and copying the graphics between notebooks:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 Epilog -> 
  Style[Text["b: 5%", Scaled[{0.05, 0.05}], {-1, -1}], 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, 
   PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]]

Export["test.pdf", %]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think I knew this, but I had forgotten.  Thanks for the reminder. +1

Comment: +1 I like this much better than the global `$FrontEnd` setting because the latter severely messes up the display of things like `MatrixForm[...]` where custom parentheses "operators" are needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with your method the formatting is wrong if your plot also includes a matrix with expanded parentheses. The `(` and `)` surrounding a matrix will simply become fixed height symbols because turning off the operator substitution prevents *Mathematica* from building them out of extensible parts.

Comment: @Jens You can always set local `Style` for single elements and combine them with `Row` or use low-level constructs like `StyleBox` and `RowBox`. For example, `MatrixForm[{{Row[{1,Style["%",PrivateFontOptions->{"OperatorSubstitution"->False}]},BaseStyle->FontFamily->"Helvetica"],2},{3,4}}]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Sure - but then you're back to what I called "finger painting" in my answer... but at least you're getting nice looking output with your approach.

Comment: @Jens You are right: the font handling in *Mathematica* is still far from what one would expect and "is subject to change" in future versions (cited from the [Documentation page for `PrivateFontOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PrivateFontOptions.html)). At the moment we have only ugly workarounds, but it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It will take some finger-painting to cobble together a combination of different fonts that look right together and have a percent sign that looks like sans-serif . Not a real solution, but maybe this will look more consistent to you:

```
Style["label text: 5 %", FontFamily -> "Monaco"]
```

[image]

Or you could do this:

```
Row[{Style["label text: 5", FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  Style["%", FontFamily -> "Monaco"]}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Looking at the exported `PDF` file containing `Style[5 %, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]` in a text editor, there is in fact a font descriptor for the `Mathematica1` font embedded where the percent sign should be rendered. One can manually delete the descriptors containing `Mathematica1` to get a `PDF` that displays the `%` correctly in an external `PDF` viewer. However, I'm not sure if this can be done automatically in a sufficiently robust way. And the problem remains that such modified `PDF` files can't be directly re-imported into *Mathematica* unless you first outline the fonts as [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16956/245).