# Formatting an equation on a plot

Tags: plotting, formatting, text, labeling

I am trying to label a plot with an equation. The problem is that Mathematica formats things *almost* well but not exactly. The parenthesis are of the wrong size, and the powers are not high enough.

For example:

```
testplot = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
Overlay[{testplot, 
        Text[(10^-3/\[Beta])^2  (("1")/g') < 2, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}]}, 
        Alignment -> {0.9, 0.85}
       ]
```

I need the equation to look like it would on Latex, but here is what I get instead:
[image: Mathematica evaluates the expression instead]

I tried putting the equation between "" but the parenthesis would be the wrong size and the powers are off. Just like this:

[image: Formatting the equation as text]

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
L.

Comment: Here are two suggestions: 1. type `""`, then go between the quotes, press Ctrl-9 and type the equation using "2D notation".  2. use TraditionalForm and HoldForm.  The second one gives better spacing around `<`.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/44g6prc26sy7xsf/Screenshot%202014-02-19%2017.57.11.png

Comment: Actually, (1.) above doesn't give a very good result.  However, if you type the formula in a text cell the same way (starting with Ctrl-9), then copy and paste it into a string, it will be formatted much better, with proper spacing.

Comment: That helps a lot but still does not fix the parenthesis problem, which I want to show exactly as it is. If it's the the power of 2, they stay as they are, but if they are (1/g), then Mathematica tried to simply the equation for me.

Comment: If I type into a text cell (insert it with Alt-7), I get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbc3dbdg5nweg4f/Screenshot%202014-02-19%2018.32.56.png  Then you can copy that into a string. I realize this is not generally a good solution, but it's at least a workaround, so you can move on with your work and not get stuck at annoying little details like this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the OP almost had the (or *a*) solution entering the formula between quotes.  The only step I added was to create an inline cell (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-9) before typing the first parenthesis.  I also wrapped the string with `Text` to get the output typeset in `TraditionalForm`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the fraction bigger, you can use `Style` to set [`FractionBoxOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FractionBoxOptions.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The whole issue of formating on plots and graphics in M really needs an overhaul. There should be a simple way to use Latex directly to do this. Matlab supports using Latex directly for plots. I do not see why M can't do the same.

Comment: @Nasser Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16955/running-external-pdflatex-command-and-importing-the-generated-pdf-document

Answer (score 2):

One way to format formula, where one enjoys a complete control on it, is the using of the Box language. This way, for instance:

```
    RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[RawBoxes[
    StyleBox[
     RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[
        RowBox[{"(", FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[10, "-3"], "\[Beta]"],
           ")"}], 2], "(", 
       FractionBox[1, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(\[Prime]\)]\)"], 
       ")", "<", 2}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity, FontSize -> 16, 
     FontSlant -> Italic]], Scaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]  ]
```

That is what should appear on the screen:
[image]
You can play with the FontSize and occasionally with the FonSlant (needed, or not). You can possibly add FontFace->Bold, if desired.

In case you like this idea you might be interested in the following tutorials:
Menu/Help/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes
Menu/Help/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes
guide/LowLevelNotebookStructure
Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one because something like `a (1/g)` is always converted to `a/g` and no `HoldForm` helps. Your label falls in the same category which means the form you want will always be destroyed by *Mathematica* except when you work with a string. Unfortunately, the rendering of a string formula differs from the usual input and here on Linux I cannot get the parenthesis large and the overall formula looks awful.

One crappy idea is to input your label in a input cell which is in `TraditionalForm` and then convert it into a Bitmap with Cell->ConvertTo. This image (!!) can then be used as label which looks OK here

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Nevertheless, I'm keen to hear other alternatives.

Comment: +1 for being so bold to propose "crappy" ideas.