# Simple ways to evaluate a derivative at a point?

Tags: evaluation, calculus-and-analysis

The contrast in behavior between, say,

```
f[x_] = Sin[x^2];
f'[2]
```

vs.

```
u[x_, y_] = Cos[x + y^2];
```

[image]

has always bothered my students---and me! (Why *does* it do it this way?)

Anyway, I tell them to handle ${\partial u\over \partial x}\Big|_{x=2}$ via

[image]

Is this the "simplest" way? How else might we accomplish this?

I realize that this is a subjective question, but our context is this is a class where we use *Mathematica* as a tool rather than a class centered on *Mathematica* itself. Thus, I want to keep the commands and code required as reasonably elementary as possible (and preferably resembling their paper-and-pencil mathematical work).

Comment: Seems to be a dupe of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11278); anyway, look up `SeriesCoefficient[]`.

Comment: @texasAUtiger I have edited your question; but in the process may be answered it? In other words what's wrong with `Derivative[1, 0][u][2, y]`?

Comment: @J. M.: I see what you mean, but unlike the first answer in the link I don't want to appeal to limits since we aren't emphasizing what a partial derivative is but rather just need to evaluate partials at values to accomplish other things. The second answer does address the issue, but I'd say the code is more complicated than a replacement rule. YMMV of course.

Comment: @chris: Indeed I think you have. I re-edited it to show what I do, leaving you room to formally answer the question with what you had. I just did not know that Derivative[...] functioned differently than using the partial symbol in the palette (at least in the sense here).

Comment: You may find [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3791/245) useful, too.

Comment: Related: [Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/) By the way, do you understand why there is contrast in behavior?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: I do not know *why* they make that line under the second box of code behave the way it does.

Comment: I ve updated my answer thanks to the help of @rojo so that the output looks exactly as you had typeset.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use as input:

```
 Derivative[1, 0][u][2, y]
```

You can implement the formating rule (Thanks to @Rojo)

```
 Format[Derivative[i_, j_][a_]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]"^(i + j), a}]/
   Row[Row[{"\[PartialD]", #}] & /@ {"x"^i, "y"^j}] 
 Format[(h : Derivative[i_, j_][a_])[x0_, y0_]] := 
   RawBoxes@SubscriptBox[RowBox[{MakeBoxes@h, "\[VerticalLine]"}], 
   MakeBoxes@Row[{Row[{x, "=", x0}], ",", Row[{y, "=", y0}]}]]
```

so that

```
   Derivative[1, 2][u][2, 3]
```

returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I arbitrary assumed the variables were `x,y` 
since I have no way to know from the input alone what the variables are.

This solution also works with input such as

```
Derivative[1, 2][f][1, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Derivative[0, 0][f][1, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Derivative[2, 0][f][1, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More generally,
provided you use (from @Jens see link below)

```
Derivative /:
MakeBoxes[Derivative[\[Alpha]__][f1_][vars__Symbol],
               TraditionalForm] :=
Module[{bb, dd, sp},
            MakeBoxes[dd, _] ^=
            If[Length[{\[Alpha]}] == 1, "\[DifferentialD]", "\[PartialD]"];
            MakeBoxes[sp, _] ^= "\[ThinSpace]";
            bb /: MakeBoxes[bb[x__], _] := RowBox[Map[ToBoxes[#] &, {x}]];
            FractionBox[ToBoxes[bb[dd^Plus[\[Alpha]], f1]],
            ToBoxes[Apply[bb,  Riffle[Map[bb[dd, #] &, 
            Select[({vars}^{\[Alpha]}), (# =!= 1 &)]], sp]]]]]


D[u[x,y,z],{x,2},{y,3},{z,2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or extending the above rule to arbitrary dimensions (again from @Rojo I am just a secretary here !)

```
Format[Derivative[i__][a_]] := 
Row[{"\[PartialD]"^Total[{i}], a}]/ 
Times @@ MapIndexed[Subscript["\[PartialD]x", First@#2]^#1 &, {i}]
```

and

```
Format[(h : Derivative[i__][a_])[vals__]] := 
RawBoxes@SubscriptBox[RowBox[{MakeBoxes@h, "\[VerticalLine]"}], 
ToBoxes@Row[ Riffle[MapIndexed[ 
Row[{Subscript["x", First@#2], "=", #1}] &, {vals}], ","]]]
```

so that

```
Derivative[2, 3, 1][u][1, 2, 3]
```

returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This formatting is also found in [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5792/245), where I give another link to the Wolfram Blog.

Comment: @Jens right! I was trying to find out where I pinched that formatting. I used to use a package called `DFormat` which your method made obsolete. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could add an input alias such as

```
AppendTo[CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, InputAliases], 
 "der" -> SuperscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
   TagBox[RowBox[{"(", "\[Placeholder]", ")"}], Derivative]]]
```

and then use `Esc`+`der`+`Esc`, and enter the derivatives separated by commas

[image: Mathematica graphics]