# How to typeset and evaluate $u \big|_a^b$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, formatting

Sometimes I need to evaluate an expression at the end points. e.g. the right hand side of $\int_a^bf(x)\textrm{d}x=F(x)\big|_a^b$. $F(x)$ could be complicated so I can't just substitute the values by hand. I currently do it this way:

```
(m[a]-m[b] /. m[x_] -> u)
```

But this introduces a new variable `m` and doesn't look very elegant. I'm looking for a built-in notation and/or a function for this purpose.

Comment: How about defining a function `r[u_, a_, b_] := u[b] - u[a]` and applying it to replace rule `u[x] /. u[x] -> r[u, a, b]`. It will yield: `-u[a] + u[b]` or for different function `u[x] /. u[x] -> r[F, a, b]` it will yield `-F[a] + F[b]`

Comment: @WojciechArtichowicz: Actually I don't have FUNCTION `F[x]`, it's just an EXPRESSION `u`. I would want some function like `diff[u,{x,a,b}]` more.

Comment: Could you provide an actual simple example of such expression?

Comment: `First@Differences[expr /. {{x->a}, {x->b}}]`?  Or `(expr /. x->b) - (expr /. x->a}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff = Function[{expr}, 
   Subtract @@ (expr /. {{#1 -> #3}, {#1 -> #2}})] &

longComplexExpr[x] // diff[x, 1, 3]
(* - longComplexExpr[1] + longComplexExpr[3] *)
```

So for integrals:

```
Integrate[x^2, x] // diff[x, 1, 3]
(* 26/3 *)

Integrate[x^2, {x, 1, 3}]
(* 26/3 *)
```

Answer (score 8):

I've had a play to try and get a slightly more stylistic solution by creating a new template for the form you want and then assigning it an `InputAlias`, following closely the work [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17978/representation-of-product-with-exclusions).

The code below will allow you to access the template
[image]
by simply typing <kbd>esc</kbd>`barEval`<kbd>esc</kbd>.

It will then evaluate the function at the limits and take the difference, as defined in the BarEvaluate function:

[image]

Some limitations are:

1. I've been a little hacky in trying to get a longer vertical bar, maybe someone can come up with a better way of producing it? (On my system I can get a proper LaTex one through the [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package).
2. You might need to adapt it for cases when your function `F` takes more than just the single parameter.

Code:

```
SetAttributes[BarEvaluate, HoldAll]

BarEvaluate[f_, limits_] := f[limits[[1]]] - f[limits[[2]]]

BarEvaluate /: MakeBoxes[BarEvaluate[f_, {a_, b_}], TraditionalForm] :=
  TemplateBox[{ToBoxes[f], ToBoxes[a], ToBoxes[b]}, 
  "conditionalProduct", 
  DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{#, 
   SubsuperscriptBox[
    StyleBox["\[VerticalSeparator]", "Subsubtitle"], 
    AdjustmentBox[#2, BoxBaselineShift -> 1], 
    AdjustmentBox[#3, BoxBaselineShift -> -1]]}] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"BarEvaluate", "[", 
   RowBox[{#, ",", "{", #2, ",", #3, "}"}], "]"}] &)]

aliases = Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases];
newAliases = 
  Join[InputAliases /. 
aliases, {"barEval" -> 
 TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", 
   "\[Placeholder]"}, "barEvaluate", 
  DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{#, 
       SubsuperscriptBox[
        StyleBox["\[VerticalSeparator]", "Subsubtitle"], 
        AdjustmentBox[#2, BoxBaselineShift -> 1], 
        AdjustmentBox[#3, BoxBaselineShift -> -1]]}] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"BarEvaluate", "[", 
       RowBox[{#, ",", "{", #2, ",", #3, "}"}], "]"}] &)]}];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> newAliases];
```

Comment: Very useful answer for much broader cases than here. I wish I knew how to search for stuff like that without knowing the keyword `InputAliases` +1 ofc

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version that should typeset and evaluate the way you want. The first step is to use a symbol that supports vertical spanning, and looks like a bar. There are several such symbols, `|`, `\[VerticalSeparator]`, `\[VerticalLine]`, `\[VerticalLine]`, `\[RightBracketingBar]` and perhaps some others. I think `\[VerticalLine]` works best, so I will use that symbol. Next, one needs to restrict the spanning, so that only the selected portion influences the spanning. So, the basic plan is to use the boxes:

```
RawBoxes @ SubsuperscriptBox[
    RowBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[VerticalLine]"}],
    "\[Placeholder]",
    "\[Placeholder]"
]
```

[image]

An example:

```
RawBoxes @ SubsuperscriptBox[
    RowBox[{FractionBox[SuperscriptBox["x","2"],"3"],"\[VerticalLine]"}],
    "1",
    "2"
]
```

[image]

By including the bar inside of a [`SubsuperscriptBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsuperscriptBox), the spanning will only consider whatever is placed inside `\[SelectionPlaceholder]`. For example:

```
RawBoxes @ RowBox[{
    FractionBox[SuperscriptBox["x","3"],"4"],
    "+",
    SubsuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"x","\[VerticalLine]"}],"1","2"]
}]
```

[image]

You will notice that the min size of the bar and the spacing is a bit off, so the following version should look better (I also turned off the [`SpanSymmetric`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpanSymmetric) option):

```
CellPrint @ Cell[
    BoxData @ SubsuperscriptBox[
        RowBox[{
            FractionBox[SuperscriptBox["x","2"],"3"],
            StyleBox["\[VerticalLine]",
                SpanSymmetric->False,
                SpanMinSize->1.5
            ]
        }],
        RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", "1"}],
        RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", "2"}]
    ],
    "Input"
]
```

[image]

This produces a box structure that should look the way you want. Now, to make it evaluatable, let's define an `EvaluatedAt` function:

```
EvaluatedAt[expr_, Automatic, min_, max_] := EvaluatedAt[
    expr,
    Replace[Reduce`FreeVariables[expr], {{v_,___}->v, _->None}],
    min,
    max
]

EvaluatedAt[expr_, x_, min_, max_] := (expr /. x->max) - (expr /. x->min)
```

A couple examples:

```
EvaluatedAt[1/x^2, x, 1, 2]
EvaluatedAt[1/x, Automatic, 1, 2]
```

> -3/4
>
> -1/2

In the second example with [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic), `EvaluatedAt` looks for the first free variable in `expr` and then does the desired arithmetic.

Now, we are ready to create an input alias that both typesets as desired, and evaluates as desired:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"at"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "Automatic", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"},
    "EvaluatedAt",
    DisplayFunction->(
        SubsuperscriptBox[
            RowBox[{
                #1,
                StyleBox[
                    "\[VerticalLine]",
                    SpanMinSize->1.5,
                    SpanSymmetric->False
                ]
            }],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #3}],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #4}]
        ]&
    )
];
```

And, here's another version where you specify the variable to be replaced:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"at2"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"},
    "EvaluatedAt",
    DisplayFunction->(
        SubsuperscriptBox[
            RowBox[{
                #1,
                StyleBox[
                    "\[VerticalLine]",
                    SpanMinSize->1.5,
                    SpanSymmetric->False
                ]
            }],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #2, "=", #3}],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #4}]
        ]&
    )
];
```

And here is an animation showing both in action:

[image]

Finally, all the necessary code in one code block:

```
EvaluatedAt[expr_, Automatic, min_, max_] := EvaluatedAt[
    expr,
    Replace[Reduce`FreeVariables[expr], {{v_,___}->v, _->None}],
    min,
    max
]

EvaluatedAt[expr_, x_, min_, max_] := (expr /. x->max) - (expr /. x->min)

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"at"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "Automatic", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"},
    "EvaluatedAt",
    DisplayFunction->(
        SubsuperscriptBox[
            RowBox[{
                #1,
                StyleBox[
                    "\[VerticalLine]",
                    SpanMinSize->1.5,
                    SpanSymmetric->False
                ]
            }],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #3}],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #4}]
        ]&
    )
];

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"at2"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"},
    "EvaluatedAt",
    DisplayFunction->(
        SubsuperscriptBox[
            RowBox[{
                #1,
                StyleBox[
                    "\[VerticalLine]",
                    SpanMinSize->1.5,
                    SpanSymmetric->False
                ]
            }],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #2, "=", #3}],
            RowBox[{"\[MediumSpace]", #4}]
        ]&
    )
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff = {x, a, b} \[Function] expr \[Function] #2 - # & @@ (Function @@ {x, expr}) /@ {a, b}
```

The usage of `diff` is the same as that in [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp)'s answer.