# Properly Format Vertical Bar with Supersubscript

Tags: format, text-formatting

I'm having trouble emulating the following (extra long) vertical bar format in a text cell:

[image]

The closest I could get to in a text cell is:

[image]

which doesn't look great; it's underlying code is

```
 Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{
    SuperscriptBox["e", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"-", "s"}], " ", "t"}]], 
    RowBox[{"f", "(", "t", ")"}]}], 
   SubsuperscriptBox["\[VerticalSeparator]", "0", "N"]}], 
  TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->TraditionalForm]], "Text"]
```

I can't figure out how to stretch the vertical bar so it looks how you would appear in a textbook.  Somehow I need the vertical bar to strectch vertically more than it defaults to.  This is standard format for a textbook, so it would seem it must be possible in Mathematica.  I tried the limitsposition option, does not seem to help with what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the following https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180769/45431

Comment: @CarlWoll Was able to modify your solution.  I'll place it here in case anyone is interested.    ty

Answer (score 1):

Using Carl Woll's code:

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{
    SuperscriptBox["e", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"-", "s"}], " ", "t"}]], 
    RowBox[{"f", "(", "t", ")"}]}], 
   SubsuperscriptBox[StyleBox["\[VerticalSeparator]","EB Garamond",FontSize->25],AdjustmentBox["\[Placeholder]",BoxBaselineShift->1.28],AdjustmentBox["\[Placeholder]",BoxBaselineShift->-1.44]]}], TraditionalForm]]]], "Text"]
```

It now looks like

[image]