# Too much spacing in f(x)?

Tags: notebooks

When I enter `f(x)` in Mathematica, the `f(x)` appears as `f (x)`. There's too much space between `f` and `(x)`. How do I enter `f(x)`? For eg) ab appears normal in Mathematica but when I enter `f(x)` there's extra space between `f` and `(x)`.

Comment: *Mathematica* uses square brackets instead of parentheses for functions.  Try `f[x]` rather than `f(x)`.

Comment: I'm practicing maths on my computer so the symbols need to be same.

Comment: If you're practicing formatting mathematical statements, _Mathematica_ may not be the best tool for that. Maybe try LaTeX or a similar system, such as LibreOffice's mathematical formula editor. _Mathematica_ needs to adhere to certain conventions to be usable as a language, and one of these conventions is that functions are written `f[x]`. This is because _Mathematica_ allows and intends for `f(x)` to be interpreted as `f * x`, which is where the extra space comes from.

Comment: The spacing will be fine as long as you make sure you're entering the expression in `TraditionalForm`. You can do this in an ordinary input cell by following the steps I described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3852/245). But you have to distinguish between input cells and mathematical typesetting. If you want solely the latter, it would be better to choose an appropriate cell style from the `Format` menu first.

Comment: Thanks. Going to Cell -> Convert to -> Traditional Format worked.

Comment: Do note that `ab` in Mathematica is interpreted as a single symbol, not $a\times b$.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `f(x)` in Mathematica. These are the steps. Open preferences, and look for `CommonDefaultFormatTypes` then change the `Input` and `Output` to `TraditionalFormat`, like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can write

```
  Plot(sin(x),{x,-Pi,Pi})
```

and

```
f(x_) := x^2;
Plot(f(x), {x, 0, 2})
```

and it work

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You'll get this message from Mathematica first time

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can click `Always` so it do not show again.

I would not use this method as it can cause problems as the message above says, but it is something you can try if you want to enter math as traditional format.